# Instagram embeds render HTML in caption

Tags: embed, instagram

It seems today the captions on instagram embeds have started to output HTML instead of the rendered text.

See here: https://www.qthotelsandresorts.com/melbourne/qt-blog/viktor-rolf-fashion-artists/

I noticed this also happens on Instagram's own website
https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/
[image]
Is there anything wrong with Instagrams code at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a temporary issue with html entities being encoded, it's fixed now.